# bower install throws 'V8_Fatal / C stack trace'

Tags: angularjs, bower, bower-install

### Problem:

I want to install my `bower_components` and it is working, when I have for example only the dependency `"angular": "1.5.3"`. But when I have `"angular": "1.5.3"` + `"angular-aria": "1.5.3"` I got the following fatal error:

### Terminal:

```
...:~/...$ bower install

#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Failed to create ICU collator, are ICU data files missing?
#

==== C stack trace ===============================

 1: V8_Fatal
 2: v8::internal::Collator::InitializeCollator(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>)
 3: v8::internal::Runtime_CreateCollator(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
 4: 0x262318f0963b
Illegal instruction
```

### bower.json

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "description": "...",
  "main": "js/services/app.module.js",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "...",
      "email": "..."
    },
    {
      "name": "...",
      "email": "..."
    }
  ],
  "license": "...",
  "homepage": "",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.3",
    "angular-animate": "1.5.3",
    "angular-aria": "1.5.3",
    "angular-messages": "1.5.3",
    "angular-material": "1.1.0-rc2",
    "angular-material-data-table": "0.10.9",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

### Additional details:

We are working behind a proxy.
But I don't think this is the problem.
When I do `bower install` first time with above settings, it is working. When I have my `bower_components` folder in the project directory and then run `bower install` I get the error.